# Finding the numbers of primes $<n$ by counting sums of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I start by considering Fermats theorem that $4n+1$ primes are the sum of two primes.
I then consider all such sums of positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2<n$

These can be found in in a circle segment between y=0 and x=y with radius $ \sqrt{n} $   and the numbers in this segment is approximately $\sqrt{n}^2\pi/8=n\pi/8$ representing the number of pairs.

Such a segment containing the x- or y axis will contain more numbers than if otherwise oriented, but I assume this discrepancy will diminish - relatively - for large n, and therefore the segment formula will represent the numbers in the segment in a reasonable way.

I now proceed but rather than trying to count the primes I list the challenges ahead. I note that the expression $\sqrt{n}^2\pi/8=n\pi/8$ is very far from  what is usually seen as the numbers of primes below a certain number n, and I therefore assume the challenges are formidable.

1. I first assume (without proof or complete knowledge) that the number of 4n+3 and 4n+1 primes are - relatively - the same, i.e. the limit of their ratio is one as n goes to infinity.
2. I only count half the numbers in the segment, disregarding pairs with even-even or odd-odd squares (since their sums cannot be of the type 4n+1). This is evened out by the 4n+3 numbers so the number $n\pi/8$ is still a valid estimate, using proper corrections below. (I note that the prime 2 is also missing in my formalism).
3. I must also disregard the sums of squares made by pairs, which are not primes. These are usually sums which can be represented 2 ways and therefore appear in pair of pairs. I consider also the Pythagorean number which can be considered doubles if 0 is included such as $3^2+4^2=5^2+0^2$.
4. I must also disregard pairs of multiples of pairs which originally contributed to the prime count. We have for example $2^2+1^2=5$ with the multiple $ (2*3)^2+(1*3)^2=45$ (multiples of even numbers are already disregarded by my  decision to disregard sums of squares made up by even-even pairs).
5. As numbers progress to higher n there will be numbers who can be represented as sums of squares in three different ways such as for 325, $325=18^2+1=15^2+10^2=6^2+17^2$. Similarly some larger numbers may be represented in an arbitrary number of different ways.

This last phenomenon makes me uneasy. My question is: do you believe these numbers will be significant or will the ratio between these numbers and the prime numbers go to 0 as n goes to infinity?

(Plus: have I forgotten some other necessary corrections?)

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin

Comment: Please: Things like TeX and MathJax were not invented for the purpose of writing things like $sqrt(n)^2pi/8$ instead of $\sqrt{n}^2\pi/8$, or $2*3$ instead of $2\cdot3$ or $2\times 3$. You're eating mashed potatoes with your fingers when silverware is available. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank a lot, I have tried to download something like Tex but it was overwhelming. It is not that people weren´t ready to help me; they simply assumed I knew more than I did. I actually picked up a few tricks from Wolfram alpha, perhaps I should have written $Sqrt(n)$ with capital S ? I now see that was wrong too.

Comment: @MikaelJensen : your last question about "these numbers" isn't really possible to answer at this point. You have hinted at the description of a set of integers (certain sums of two squares), but you haven't given enough information to specify exactly what set you're talking about.

Comment: I am thinking about numbers which are represented by 3 and more pairs of sums of 6 numbers (2+2+2) or more. I am not sure how to compensate for their occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Greg Martin indicates that this may be off target. It is, however, not widely known, and may help anyway.

The number of positive integers (that are sums of two squares) up to some large $x$ is asymptotically
$$  \frac{0.7642 \; x}{\sqrt{\log x}}.  $$
This is the final few pages in Volume II of [LeVeque](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486425398.html), where the infinite product that gives $0.7642...$ is specified and an error bound is given. Theorem 7-28 on page 261 of Volume II, they put two volumes into one and kept each set of page numbers.

This is larger than the number of primes up to $x$ by a factor of $0.7642 \sqrt{\log x}.$

Comment: First of all, I don't think you mean what you wrote in the first sentence. Second, the OP seems to be describing some sort of sieving on the set of sums of two squares, so its full counting function is presumably not directly relevant to $\pi(x)$.

Comment: @GregMartin, see what you mean. Got into FaceBook chat. I admit, I cannot tell about your sieving suggestion. I also have never learned asymptotics for the count of numbers that are *primitively* represented as two squares, meaning not divisible by $4$ or by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

Comment: It might still turn out to be a component in the calculation.

Comment: Actually I got som help from a comment on another recent question by or Alexey Burdin, writing  "exactly 2 ways -- oeis.org/A025303". I may have what I need now (not to say I am capable of solving the problem). I still need an OK on the issue of 4n+1 vs 4n+3 primes though (can I assume their limit of ratio of occurrence =1?).

Comment: @MikaelJensen, yes, the ratio of occurrence goes to one. Given any number $N,$ there are $\varphi(N)$ infinite sets of primes, split up according to the remainder when such $p$ is divided by $N.$ These infinite sets of primes occur with equal frequency in the limit.